# How to Send Mag::Log error using Whatsapp?

Tags: magento-1.9, whatsapp

I am using Event Observer for getting custom values, How can i send my EventObserver log message by whatsapp message?

Comment: Please share what you have done till now.

Comment: Using twilio finished my task.